# Is there a way to marry std::ranges::transform and std::ranges::copy_if?

Tags: c++, std-ranges

I need to copy projections of some elements from one range to another in case they meet the predicate.

- The `std::ranges::copy_if` uses projection only to pass the result to
  the predicate, projection result can’t be copied; only the original
  data.
- The necessary transformation could be done with the
  `std::ranges::transform`, but it copies all elements, since there is
  no `std::ranges::transform_if`.

Is there a way to copy the projections without allocating intermediate containers and making excessive intermediate copies?

Thus:

```
std::ranges::transform(src,temp,op);
std::ranges::copy_if (temp,dest,pred);
```

works, but requires `temp` container and excessive copy.

Of course, this can easily be implemented with `std::ranges::for_each`, but I am curious if there is more straightforward solution in ranges?

And of course I can write something like:

```
template <class InputIt, class OutputIt, class Pred, class Proj>
void transform_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt dest, Pred pred, Proj projection)
{
   while (first != last) {
      if (pred(*first)) {
         *dest++ = projection(*first);
      }
      ++first;
   }
}
```

but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is more simple and straightforward solution in ranges.

Comment: I don't think so. Note that boost contains this function, but it's just as well to use your version if you're not already pulling in such a heavy dependency.

Comment: just use `std::view::filter` in place of `std::ranges::copy_if`. Which version of C++ standard do you use? 20/23?

Comment: @MarekR, I use the latest version of C++ (with all experimental features). My case is that `src` is the array of indexes and projection gets elements by this indexes from another container. I am not sure `std::view::filter` will do here, since I don't have an idea how it would convert dispersed array data in one range. If this could be done, I could prepare demo so that you could pinpoint the `std::view::filter` usage (in case this can't be easily answered in the original terms of the question).

Comment: Please provide some example so it is clear what is a goal. Is this ok: https://godbolt.org/z/xrThhj5vo ?

Comment: @MarekR, thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for! With one reservation, I wanted to copy it in the resulting vector with `std::back_inserter` like [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Trn883rqT), but this last step was easy when you have showed the key part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ranges library includes both *range algorithms*, which are applied to ranges eagerly, and *range adaptors*, which are applied to views lazily. Adaptors can be composed into pipelines, so that their actions take place as the view is iterated.

```
auto result = src | std::views::filter(pred) | std::views::transform(op);
std::ranges::copy(result, dst);
```

`result` is lazily evaluated thus this won't create any unnecessary copies.

Comment: Thank you. In my case I need to make filtering on transformed values, so am I correct that I should swap them, meaning with that pipes applies left to right? On the lazy evaluation, am I correct that in case transform takes values by indexes in index array and then values are filtered, this won't create any consequent range (array in memory) to keep these values together and they will be represented as range/view just virtually for the moment of execution? Am I correct that temporary `result` provided for code simplicity only and could be safely substituted in `copy`?

Comment: Yes, you can swap the order and substitute directly into copy. std::views avoids the memory allocation involved with a temporary range.

Comment: Shouldn't `std::ranges::copy_result` be used here?

Comment: @DamirTenishev `copy_result` is the return type (an alias of `std::ranges::in_out_result`).  How will you use it exactly?

Comment: Ops, sorry. Thank you. I just got another error while trying to implement this on complex structure and messed with the description at [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/copy) where `copy_result` more visible than `copy`, so I messed type with template name.